# allocating ram shows double the ram usage in task manager

Tags: c, windows-7, malloc

Doing some profiling (mem & speed) I've been stomped by the fact that win7 seems to be allocating exactly double the RAM I ask for... Note this is the first time I do such active profiling on win7, so I don't really know what to expect.

I'm allocating precise amounts of RAM in a loop using an express edition of MSVC under win7 (64-bit).  The application is compiled and runs in 32 bit.

I allocate 24 MB of ram and the task manager shows my app as using 48MB (under all memory columns, including committed, since I'm actually memcopy'ing within the new regions).  When I get 24 more (should now be 48MB), my app jumps to 96, etc.

These are allocated as 1,000,000  24 byte structs.

I've searched on the net but have found nothing to match my observations exactly.

Anyone have a clue?

If this is just OS trickery (or incompetence?), is there any tool which can give me the real memory consumption of a process?  (its hard to find leaks, when the app gushes to begin with ;-)

[----------- edited, additional info -----------]

Note (by the path in the console title bar) that I am building in Release mode (using all default "empty" project settings of MSVC 2010), so there is no additional "debugging" memory being allocated (which can be quite extensive on some projects).

here is a short, complete C app which illustrates the behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef struct myStruct MYS;
struct myStruct {
    u32 type;
    union {
        u32 value; 
        char * str;
        void * data;
        MYS ** block;
        MYS * plug;
    };
    u32 state, msg,  count, index;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, j;
    MYS *ref;
    printf ("size of myStruct: %d\n\n", sizeof(MYS));
    for(i=0; i < 10; i ++){
        printf("allocating started...\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 1000000 ; j ++){
            ref = (MYS *) malloc(sizeof(MYS));
            assert(ref);
            memset(ref, 0, sizeof(MYS));
        }
        printf("   Done... Press 'enter' for Next Batch\n");
        _getch();
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and an image which shows the memory on my machine after one loop.  Every other run, it adds ~48MB instead of 24MB!

[image: process info after 1 loop (should be ~24MB)]

Comment: can you show the line where you allocate memory?

Comment: You sure that struct is really 24 bytes? There might be some alignment going on that pads it.

Comment: Edited question... I added a full code example with additional building details and a pic of my task manager after one loop. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Maybe the OS is proactively reserving more memory since it knows it will be doing so in other iterations (perhaps hinted by the compiler)?  Maybe the fact that you're leaking memory is affecting it?  Have you tried letting it run through all 10 iterations?

Comment: Check out SysInternal's [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533). Might shed some light on the program's memory consumption.

Comment: wrt leaking... I'll do a test... intriguing comment.  wrt do all 10 iterations yes... it's a 470MB at the end.   If it where "pre-emptive" allocation, I'd expect 24MB to be allocated more overall... not at each iteration.  also, by all I've read, the Commit size should somehow reflect the real allocation... like I see on apps (not of mine) for which I know the mem allocation is often half the "Working Set".

Comment: VMMAP - thanks... that will definitely help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to a combination of padding, internal housekeeping structures, and memory alignment restrictions.

When you invoke `malloc(size)`, you don't actually get a buffer of `size` bytes. You get a buffer that is *at least* of `size` bytes. This is because, for efficiency reasons, your OS prefers to hand memory buffers in just a couple of different sizes and will not tailor buffers to save space. For instance, inf you ask for 24 bytes on Mac OS, you'll get a buffer of 32 bytes (a waste of 25%).

Add to that allocation overhead the structures your OS uses to manage `malloc`ed buffers (probably accounting for a few extra bytes per allocation), and the fact that padding may increase the size of your object (to a multiple of your compiler's preferred alignment), and you'll see that allocating millions of small objects into individual buffers is very expensive.

Long story short: allocate just one big buffer of `sizeof (YourType) * 1000000` and you shouldn't see any noticeable overhead. Allocate a million of `sizeof (YourType)` objects, and you'll end up wasting a lot of space.

Comment: thanks, so I should implement my own (memory efficient) pooled allocators for these structs?  I will be handling millions of these small structs.  something which allocates n number at a time and then keeps tabs on how many it has left before the next allocation is required (and vice-versa for free'ing).

Comment: Yes, if you need to handle lots and lots of small allocations, you should create an allocator that uses `malloc` to reserve large chunks of memory at once.

Comment: btw, I did quite a few tests and it seems that all malloc calls on my win7 box add an extra 20-30 bytes (average based on millions of allocs of different sizes).  so I guess the system's allocator itself is quite memory hungry (has lots of values it tracks for any given allocation).

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is not a OS service on Windows, it is implemented by your compiler. It might have its own allocation strategy as indicated by the other answer and it is often built on top of `HeapAlloc` that has some overhead of its own.

Call [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to allocate a specific number of pages.