# RAM usage measured with GetProcessMemoryInfo is lower than measure through Task Manager

Tags: c++, windows, memory, ram, taskmanager

I have found many discussions online on why RAM usage of a process as measured by Task Manager is often higher than measured during runtime by an application's own code. For an excelent answer about that, see: [allocating ram shows double the ram usage in task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655185/allocating-ram-shows-double-the-ram-usage-in-task-manager)

However, oddly, I am finding the opposite. My measurement inside the application, using `GetProcessMemoryInfo` function, shows a higher amount of RAM usage than the Task Manager. The code is simply:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>


int main(void)
{
    uint64_t currentUsedRAM(0);

    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &info, sizeof(info));
    currentUsedRAM = info.WorkingSetSize;

    const int N(100000000);
    int *x = new int[N];        
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 1;
    }

    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &info, sizeof(info));
    currentUsedRAM = info.WorkingSetSize - currentUsedRAM;

    std::cout << "Current RAM used: " << currentUsedRAM << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output is ``Current RAM used: 400007168`, measured in bytes (e.g. around 400 Mb). However, in my Task Manager, the application process is shown as using just 381.8 Mb, which is around around 18 Mb less.

Why would that happen?

Is there a way to make these to converge to a same result?

**EDIT**:

Following the linked suggested in the commments, I also tried the *Process Explorer* software in substitution to Task Manager. With, the measurement is 391,892 Mb. It is, closer to what I get from the in-application measurement, but still quite off.

Even more importantly, I tried increasing the array size by one order of magnitude. Interestingly, the within application measurement, the Task Manager measurement and the Process Explorer measurement all also increase by one order of magnitude. It is, the difference between the within-application measurement and these softwares' also increases proportionally and goes from around 18,8 Mb (Task Manager) or 9 Mb (Process Explorer) to around 185 Mb (Task Manager) or 102 Mb (Process Explorer).

Comment: Task Manager is known not to be reliable. [How precise is Task Manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467805/how-precise-is-task-manager)

Comment: 400007168 / 1024 / 1024 is almost 381.5

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych And what does it mean exactly to divide by 1024 /1024? I think that understanding might lead to the very answer I am looking for.

Comment: @BoPersson Using th software **Process Explorer**, that is suggested in one of the answers to the question you linked to, gives 391,892 Mb. It is, closer to what I get from the in-application measurement, but still quite off. If I increase the size of the array by one order of magnitude, the amount of difference when measuring either with Task Manager or Process Explorer, also increases proportionally.

Comment: A megabyte is not 1,000,000 bytes.  It is 2 x 2 x 2 x ... x 2 x 2 = 1024 x 1024 = 1,048,576 bytes.  And 400007168 / 1048576 = 381.4765625 megabytes.  Two fingers, not ten fingers.

Comment: @HansPassant Ooops, obviously! Thanks. Quick side-note for reference in case someone else gets into that: of course, after taking that into account, my in-application measurement is almost identical to Task Manager's... except for when Gigabytes are reached. At the Gb level, I have to divide by 1000 to get identical results to Task Manager's. So, it seems that Task Manager oddly uses 1Gb = 1000Mb, while 1Mb = 1024kb, 1kb = 1024b.